# win32 ListView CustomDraw , why dwDrawStage value is alway equal to 1

Tags: listview, winapi, custom-draw

i'm working on win32 listview controls,Want to achieve CustomDraw,

but i got something strange。
I wonder why this **dwDrawStage** value is always equal to 1

```
bool rst = CreateWinEx(WC_LISTVIEW, NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS  | LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER | WS_BORDER,0,
        x,y,w,h,
        hwndParent_, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL));
```

OnListViewNotify

```
LRESULT my::listView::OnListViewNotify(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{

    NMLISTVIEW* pnmv= (NMLISTVIEW*)lParam;

    LRESULT lResult = 0;

    switch(pnmv->hdr.code)
    {
        case  NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
        {
            idebug("NM_CUSTOMDRAW\n");
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, DWL_MSGRESULT, (LONG)CustomDraw(lParam));
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return(lResult);
}
```

CustomDraw

```
LRESULT  my::listView::CustomDraw( LPARAM lParam )
{
    //NMLVCUSTOMDRAW* pLVCD = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>( pNMHDR );
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW pLVCD = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW) lParam;
    
    idebug("dwDrawStage:%d\n",pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage);

     switch(pLVCD->nmcd.dwDrawStage) 
    {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        {
            //request notifications for individual listview items
            return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
        }    
        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: //Before an item is drawn
        {
            return CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;
        }
        case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT: //Before a subitem is drawn
        {
            switch(pLVCD->iSubItem)
            {
                case 0:
                {
                    pLVCD->clrText   = RGB(255,255,255);
                    pLVCD->clrTextBk = RGB(240,55,23);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;

                }
                case 1:
                {
                    pLVCD->clrText   = RGB(255,255,0);
                    pLVCD->clrTextBk = RGB(0,0,0);
                    return CDRF_NEWFONT;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CDRF_DODEFAULT;
}
```

Want to achieve CustomDraw,but i got something strange。
I wonder why this **dwDrawStage** value is always equal to 1

info from debugging

```
hdr.code->NM_CUSTOMDRAW
dwDrawStage:1
```

thank you for sharing you wisdom and experience;

Comment: IIRC (it's been a while), your `return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW` return value should be `return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW | CDRF_DODEFAULT` (and similarly for the `CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW` case, which may also need `CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT` ORed in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the key is about return value as @Adrian Mole say.

when i return CDRF_NEWFONT or return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW the proplem was disappear.